# probrema ao pegar uma data com o search

Tags: python, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou tendo problema ao fazer uma filtragem por data nos e-mails utilizando o metodo `search`.

O código pega a data e filtra os e-mails com a data correspondente da máquina

```
data = datetime.now()
data  = data .strftime('%H')
# meu search de pesquisa
reposta,idosEmail = object.search(None,"ALL",data)
```

Comment: Editei sua postagem, mas mesmo assim está difícil de entender!

Answer (score -2):

Vc pode usar no python o método find()
Você pode consultar o uso do método em:
[1] : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).